# Rails / Heroku Novice: App doesn't start (state: crashed for Xm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Hey Guys I'm trying to deploy my app (whcih runs fine on my computer) but its not working! is there somethign I should be changing in my database.yml file or somethign? I'm locally running w. mysql..

logs: http://pastebin.com/u3q58M4N

thanks for your help!!!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"(pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)" Switch your local development environment to PostgreSQL, always develop and deploy on the same stack. – mu is too short 23 hours ago

had to change the gemfile:

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end